# Issue with WDSL Service

Tags: web-services, post, soap, postman

I am trying to develop code to use a webservice. The documentation is here: https://app.foliosdigitalespac.com/CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc. Specifically I want to use the method **GenerarTicket**.

If I use [this tool](https://wsdlbrowser.com/) and provide the link above I can generate an XML for this specific method. This is the generated XML.

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:tes="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TES.V33.CFDI.Negocios">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <tem:GenerarTicket>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:credenciales>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:Cuenta>TES030201001</tes:Cuenta>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:Password>TES030201001j+2020</tes:Password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:Usuario>TES030201001</tes:Usuario>
        </tem:credenciales>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:ticket>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:ClaveCFDI>FAC</tes:ClaveCFDI>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:Conceptos>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <tes:ConceptoR>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:Cantidad>2</tes:Cantidad>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:ClaveProdServ>84111506</tes:ClaveProdServ>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:ClaveUnidad>C81</tes:ClaveUnidad>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:Descripcion>Producto 1</tes:Descripcion>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:Importe>0.09</tes:Importe>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:NoIdentificacion>1234567890</tes:NoIdentificacion>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:Unidad>ACT</tes:Unidad>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:ValorUnitario>0.045</tes:ValorUnitario>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                </tes:ConceptoR>
                <tes:ConceptoR>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:Cantidad>5</tes:Cantidad>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:ClaveProdServ>84111506</tes:ClaveProdServ>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:ClaveUnidad>C81</tes:ClaveUnidad>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:Descripcion>Producto 2</tes:Descripcion>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:Importe>0.02</tes:Importe>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:NoIdentificacion>001</tes:NoIdentificacion>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:Unidad>ACT</tes:Unidad>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tes:ValorUnitario>0.004</tes:ValorUnitario>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                </tes:ConceptoR>
            </tes:Conceptos>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:CondicionesDePago>Condiciones De Pago</tes:CondicionesDePago>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:Emisor>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tes:Nombre>Nombre del Emisor</tes:Nombre>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tes:RegimenFiscal>601</tes:RegimenFiscal>
            </tes:Emisor>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:FormaPago>01</tes:FormaPago>
            <tes:LugarExpedicion>72000</tes:LugarExpedicion>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:MetodoPago>PUE</tes:MetodoPago>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:Moneda>MXN</tes:Moneda>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <!--Optional:-->
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:Referencia>1234</tes:Referencia>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:SubTotal>0.11</tes:SubTotal>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:Total>0.11</tes:Total>
        </tem:ticket>
    </tem:GenerarTicket>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then I can submit the request and it works as expected. If like to try this with Postman so I can write the PHP code.

I am sending a POST to https://app.foliosdigitalespac.com/CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc?function_name=GenerarTicket with the Content-Type header set to text/xml and the above XML as a raw XML body. When I click submit I get the following error.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="es-MX">The message with Action 'GenerarTicket' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Obviously I am not doing something well but cant figure what it is. I was told by the WDSL developer than I can send a POST with the correct information and get the response. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on. The correct URL is https://app.foliosdigitalespac.com/CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc.

Then the SOAPAction header must be set to the correct Action. According to [the documentation](https://app.foliosdigitalespac.com/CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc?WSDL) the Action is *http://tempuri.org/IConexionRemota/GenerarTicket*. I was using as the Action only GenerarTicket.

Since I wanted to use PHP the corresponding code is

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://app.foliosdigitalespac.com/CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"<soapenv:Envelope\n        xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\n        xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"\n        xmlns:tes=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TES.V33.CFDI.Negocios\">\n    <soapenv:Header/>\n    <soapenv:Body>\n        <tem:GenerarTicket>\n            <!--Optional:-->\n            <tem:credenciales>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:Cuenta>TES030201001</tes:Cuenta>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:Password>TES030201001j+2020</tes:Password>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:Usuario>TES030201001</tes:Usuario>\n            </tem:credenciales>\n            <!--Optional:-->\n            <tem:ticket>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:ClaveCFDI>FAC</tes:ClaveCFDI>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:Conceptos>\n                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->\n                    <tes:ConceptoR>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:Cantidad>2</tes:Cantidad>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:ClaveProdServ>84111506</tes:ClaveProdServ>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:ClaveUnidad>C81</tes:ClaveUnidad>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:Descripcion>Producto 1</tes:Descripcion>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:Importe>0.09</tes:Importe>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:NoIdentificacion>1234567890</tes:NoIdentificacion>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:Unidad>ACT</tes:Unidad>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:ValorUnitario>0.045</tes:ValorUnitario>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                    \n                    </tes:ConceptoR>\n                    <tes:ConceptoR>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:Cantidad>5</tes:Cantidad>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:ClaveProdServ>84111506</tes:ClaveProdServ>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:ClaveUnidad>C81</tes:ClaveUnidad>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:Descripcion>Producto 2</tes:Descripcion>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:Importe>0.02</tes:Importe>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:NoIdentificacion>001</tes:NoIdentificacion>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:Unidad>ACT</tes:Unidad>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                        <tes:ValorUnitario>0.004</tes:ValorUnitario>\n                        <!--Optional:-->\n                    \n                    </tes:ConceptoR>\n                </tes:Conceptos>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:CondicionesDePago>Condiciones De Pago</tes:CondicionesDePago>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:Emisor>\n                    <!--Optional:-->\n                    <tes:Nombre>Nombre del Emisor</tes:Nombre>\n                    <!--Optional:-->\n                    <tes:RegimenFiscal>601</tes:RegimenFiscal>\n                </tes:Emisor>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:FormaPago>01</tes:FormaPago>\n                <tes:LugarExpedicion>72000</tes:LugarExpedicion>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:MetodoPago>PUE</tes:MetodoPago>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:Moneda>MXN</tes:Moneda>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:Referencia>1234</tes:Referencia>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:SubTotal>0.11</tes:SubTotal>\n                <!--Optional:-->\n                <tes:Total>0.11</tes:Total>\n            </tem:ticket>\n        </tem:GenerarTicket>\n    </soapenv:Body>\n</soapenv:Envelope>",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: text/xml",
    "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/IConexionRemota/GenerarTicket"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```